# Xcode: find in project NOT only whole words?

Tags: xcode, full-text-search

When I try to <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> for `convertPoint` in my project, it does not find existing `convertPointFromBase:`, but shows only `convertPoint:toView:` etc.

How to make it search not only whole words? I cannot find any settings about searching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the find bar klick the little triangle next to the magnifying glass. In the popup select "Show Find Options". In the revealed options select "Hits must contain search term".

Comment: And, in Xcode5, there is "Find > Text > Containing" just above the in-project search field, and one can click "Containing" and change it to "Matching", "Starting with" or "Ending with" to change the way to search.
I just got this answer from others in 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355754/project-wide-word-matching-search-on-xcode-5)