# Project wide word matching search on Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, find, match, xcode5

I'm using Xcode 5, and want to find a word (ex:variable name) not by substring match but by exact match (or prefix match). In file wide search (Command-F), I can use Textual search or regular expression search by clicking the arrow button just right of the glass icon and choosing "Edit Find Options...".
But, I cannot find any option to search on project wide search ("Find in Project", Shift-Command-F), in Xcode 5.
One thing I can do is run "grep -w" on Terminal.app. But, isn't there any way to search word in Project inside Xcode?

Comment: Agreed; it's not there.

Comment: Not sure of what you're really looking for but you can click on each component (`Find`>`Text`>`Containing`) to select from different options along with the scope (by clicking on `In Project` or `In Workspace` based on your project) of your search...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well it seems that the search tool in Xcode 5 is a bit confusing for a lot of people. In my opinion Apple should have done a better work letting the user know of what is clickable and what not... That being said, here is how you access the different options:

Once we switch to the `Find Navigator` we see 3 components (`Find`>`Text`>`Containing`)
[image]

Now, you can click on any of them to select between different options (à la jumpbar)
[image]

And finally you can also click the `In Workspace` (or `In Project`) to change the scope of your search

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode 6 the problem I was having was that my Framework folder wasn't being searched, even though it was clearly part of the project (but in /Library/Frameworks), and even when I had one of its files open with the string showing in the editor.

[image: So I clicked In Project and defined a new Scope that specified "within workspace and frameworks".]

Changing the scope from In Project to My Scope (as shown) even allowed me to find the search string in non-frameworks folders.